# Inserting multiple rows in an Oracle database with OCCI

Tags: c++, oracle

This is my first experience so OCCI so I beg your pardon if the answer is obvious.

I have a Statement object, created the usual way:

```
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO data_tab VALUES(:id, :name, :number, :when)";
m_stmt = m_conn->createStatement(sqlStatement);

m_stmt->setMaxIterations(100);
```

Then I need to loop over a few objects that I should insert into the database:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
{
    m_stmt->setInt(1, i);

    try {
        m_stmt->setString(2, data[i].client());
    }
    catch(SQLException& e)
    {
        cerr << "setString(): " << e.what();
        exit(1);
    }

    m_stmt->setDouble(3, data[i].number());
    m_stmt->setDate(4, data[i].when());

    // ...
    // Checks if maxIterations is lesser than data size,
    // oteherwise calls executeUpdate and other kind of
    // boilerplate code.
    // ...

    m_stmt->addIteration();
}
```

But the code borks in the setString method with the following output:

```
setString(): ORA-32132: maximum iterations cannot be changed
```

I believe I should get this error is I call setMaxIterations after a setXXX method but I don't do this. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should invoke `setMaxParamSize()` prior to setting a variable length parameter:

```
m_stmt->setMaxParamSize(2, 1000) // or whatever is the max length of your string.
```

Comment: Thank you, I would never find this on my own. Would you mind telling me what's the rationale behind need to do this?

Comment: @Vitor: when preparing the iterations, `Oracle` client allocates a buffer for the array of the records (of `maxIterations` size) and just reads the variables by offsetting the array by the element size in a loop. The array element size is the sum of the variables' size and hence needs to be known beforehand. This can be done dynamically but this implies breaking the array into pieces one record long (each of its own size) and calling `setMaxIteractions(1)` behind the scenes.